# Simple code for replace a div in C#

Tags: c#

I have a problem. I learn to edit html document in a simple program in C#, but i have a question.

i have a line code in HTML like that:

```
<div role = "banner" class = "TopBanner">
```

I want to change this line code in this:

```
<div role = "banner" class = "TopBanner" style = "display:none;">
```

i try to use

```
        HtmlElementCollection ElemCol= default(HtmlElementCollection);
        ElemCol= webBrowser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("div");
        foreach (HtmlElement curElement in ElemCol)
        {
            if (curElement.OuterHtml.Contains("TopBanner"))
            {
                curElement.Style = "display:none";
            }
        }
```

but is not working. my code just set `display` to `none` and don't replace the div with new text.
Any ideas to replace the div?

Comment: Trying to understand better, when you run the code, does it work as far as the `div` is no longer displayed? You just don't see it has been changed in the HTML?

Answer (score 2):

Try this code:

```
HtmlElementCollection ElemCol= default(HtmlElementCollection);
ElemCol= webBrowser.Document.GetElementsByTagName("div");
foreach (HtmlElement curElement in ElemCol)
{
    if (curElement.GetAttribute("class").Contains("TopBanner"))
    {
        curElement.SetAttribute("style", "display:none");
    }
}
```

Comment: this is like my code. is worked for another div, but i can't remove this banner only if i replace in div display:none, note in style.

Comment: Don't fully understand what you mean, but in addition to set style of element, you should try to set its whole HTML using OuterHtml property, replacing the "TopBanner" string before. The second approach may be to remove the htmlElement from Parent element at all.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [SetAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3kz0c5c3(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
       if (curElement.OuterHtml.Contains("TopBanner"))
       {
                curElement.SetAttribute("style", "display:none");= "";
       }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to use [setAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3kz0c5c3(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
curElement.setAttribute("style", "display:none")
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's something you do a lot in your program (HTML manipulation), you may want to look at a project like [CsQuery](https://github.com/jamietre/CsQuery). It may give you much better control over stuff like this. If it's only something done a few times, a full assembly may be overkill.